# Reducing $A^c\cup(A\cap B^c)\cup(A\cap B\cap C^c)\cup(A\cap B\cap C\cap D^c)\cup\cdots$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I would like to know if there is any way I can reduce or know what this whole set of operations between sets is equivalent to
$$A^c\cup(A\cap B^c)\cup(A\cap B\cap C^c)\cup(A\cap B\cap C\cap D^c)\cup\cdots$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to find the complement:

$$(A^c\cup(A\cap B^c)\cup(A\cap B\cap C^c)...)^c$$

Use de-morgan to get

$$A\cap(A^c\cup B)\cap(A^c\cup B^c\cup C)...$$
Note that: $A\cap(A^c\cup B)=A\cap B$

So now we have:

$$(A\cap B)\cap(A^c\cup B^c\cup C)...$$

Similarly, $(A\cap B)\cap(A^c\cup B^c\cup C)=A\cap B\cap C$

I think that you can see where I am going with it, the complement is:
$$A\cap B\cap C\cap D...$$

Thus, we can use de-morgan again to deduce that the original set is:

$$A^c\cup B^c\cup C^c\cup D^c...$$

In fact, you don't really have to use de-morgan, but the complement turns out to be more comfortable in my opnion...

Moreover, If you want a proof - you can easily prove it by induction.